# Two-Stage Fully-Reusable Shuttle

Tags: space-shuttle, design, reuse, ssme

In chapter 6 of [SP-4221 "The Space Shuttle Decision"](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4221/ch6.htm) they are talking about the fall of the "Two-Stage Fully Reusable Shuttle".

In one paragraph they talk about how this Two-Stage Shuttle would work:

> Fueled and cleared for launch, the Shuttle would thunder into the air
> with the thrust of **12 SSMEs** in the base of the booster. The orbiter
> would separate and fly onward, propelled by its own SSMEs. The
> booster, empty of fuel, would come down through the atmosphere and
> return to a runway at the Cape, with power from up to **12 jet engines**.
> After completing its mission in space, the orbiter would reenter and
> land on the same runway. Preparations for the next flight, covering
> both the booster and orbiter, would take as little as two weeks.

From what I can understand here it meant that there were plans to create a booster with 12 engines and 12 jet engines as well?

Were they talking about a booster with SSMEs as engines? What were the jet engines they were talking about? I've never heard anything about using jet engines in a booster before.

Also are there any pictures or prototypes ever created of such design?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There were literally dozens of different designs proposed. Page 100 of the referenced book lists more than fifty different designs, and then there are 7 pages showing thumbnail sketches of them.

Here is one booster design from Phase B of the design process. It's the first one I found with 12 SSMEs and 12 jet engines, but it may not be the only such one.

[image]

This is from Jenkins, *Space Shuttle*, the 1992 edition.

An artist's rendering of the B9U design landing from [here](https://e05.code.blog/2020/03/14/gd-convair-b9u-booster/).

[image]

The airbreathing engines were

> JF22A-4 air breathing engines powered by JP-4 fuel.

Source: [astronautix.com](http://www.astronautix.com/s/shuttler134c.html)

This is probably a typo for the JF**T**22, the Pratt and Whitney company designation for the [F-100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_F100) afterburning turbofan engine. The JFT22 is also mentioned in the book source.

Comment: A booster with its own crew? Whoa. Also, I like how this booster looks more like a spaceship than what the actual spaceship ended up looking like.

Comment: @JörgWMittag not sure about the actual feasibility but the early rounds of shuttle design produced some pretty cool stuff https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40369/6944

Comment: I think I even saw another picture mentioned on Twitter with a design for this type of shuttle configuration https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FOKU_-xXEBUus2L?format=jpg&name=medium